# ListView Array Adapter error"None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied."

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to create a fragment with a ListView with the id=lv and the ArrayAdapter doesn't seem to work

this is the fragment code

```
class Istoric : Fragment() {
    var array = arrayOf("item1","item2")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.listview_item,array)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_istoric, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val lv1: ListView = view.findViewById(R.id.lv)
        lv1.setAdapter(adapter)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass context instead of **this**

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.listview_item, array)
```